# Using location variables to access subfolders and files

Tags: regex, nginx, directory-listing

I'm trying to get nginx to `add_after_body` a file called `readme.php` at the end of every directory listing in an index.

For every subfolder, another `readme.php` can exist, which is to be added instead of the default readme that exists at the root of the folder structure. If it doesn't exist, the root one should instead be used.

So far I have the following code:

```
location /archive/ {                                                        
    autoindex on;                                                           
    add_after_body /archive/readme.php;                                     
}
```

Which forces the root readme to be used for all subdirectories of `/archive/`.

My next step is then to access the inner readme files but I'm having a hard time writing the correct regex for it. I've tried:

`/archive/([^/])/`
`/archive/(.*/)`
`/archive/(.*)/`

in combination with this code:

```
# using /archive/([^/])/ as an example
location /archive/([^/])/ {                                                 
    autoindex on;                                                           
    add_after_body /archive/$1/readme.php;                                   
}
```

but my subdirectories keep on using the root readme file and not their own version.

I've ordered these two location blocks both ways in my site config but nothing seems to change.

I know for step three I can use an if statement inside the location block to check if the file actually exists instead of blindly trying to use it, but I can't even detect the subfolders yet... What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I don't have even the slightest clue regarding nginx, so the following might be wrong. However, I've quite an idea about regular expressions and some experience with config files so I believe I can help out.

I assume that you have studied the nginx documentation so far that you are sure that the nginx engine considers locations to be in the form `/dir/`, not the form `/dir`. If this is wrong, the following is void.

Let's first look at your second regular expression, `/archive/(.*/)`. This probably won't work for a simple reason which is best explained by an example. Suppose you have a folder `/archive/a/`. `$1` will then be `a/`, and `/archive/$1/readme.php` will then be `/archive/a//readme.php`. I guess you've recognized the problem; you can solve it by changing your result string to `/archive/${1}readme.php` (note that it depends on the implementation of the regex engine which escape characters to use instead of `{}`, but without special escaping, `1` will probably considered a part of the filename instead of a variable name).

Let's now analyze the problems with your first approach, `/archive/([^/])/`. This won't work as intended unless each direct child of `/archive` has a name which is exactly one character long. That is because `[^/]` means: "One character which is not `/`".

To solve this problem, you could change it to `/archive/([^/]*)/` (note the additional `*`). `[^/]*` means "Any sequence of characters excluding `/`", or, in other words, "The sequence of characters up to the next `/`".

At this point we face the next problem: This will work only if there is only one nesting level under `/archive`, i.e. if all subdirectories are in the form `/archive/subdir/`, where `subdir` must not contain `/` itself. To solve this problem, you could change the regular expression to something like `/archive/(([^/]*/)*)` (I'll leave it to you to interpret it :-)).

Unfortunately, this expression leads to the same problem as your second one. The trailing `/` will be part of `$1`, and will lead to a `//` in the result; you can solve that problem as described above (i.e. by something like `/archive/${1}readme.php`).

Your third approach, `/archive/(.*)/`, will probably work correctly, but only for subfolders of `/archive/`, i.e. for nested folders. For `/archive/` itself, you have your first snippet, so it should work in summary.

Since it doesn't, I believe that there is another problem:

In your question, you make the impression that you left your first snippet

```
location /archive/ {                                                        
    autoindex on;                                                           
    add_after_body /archive/readme.php;                                     
}
```

in place and put your second snippet **below** it.

But eventually the nginx engine is a "first-match"-engine: If a criterion is matched, the associated action is taken, and the remaining criteria are not taken into account any more.

If I am right with this, the solution is simple: Just put the more specific criterion (i.e. the block with the regex) **above** the other one.

A last idea has to to with common regex syntax. I know many regex engines which are treating `/` as a special character which must be escaped if it should be interpreted as literal. If this applies to the nginx regex engine, you would have to change your regular expressions, replacing `/` by `\/` (provided `\` is the escape character, as is often the case). Since I don't know nginx, you'll have to find out yourself :-)

Please let us know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you for the answer however none of this unfortunately works. Changing `[^/]` to `[^/]*` does not change anything, variables are still captured normally with `$1` so I don't need the `{}` block and furthermore, if I place the match before the general case, it will be matched for any subfolder and attempt to load a potentially (leading to an error) non-existent `readme.php` which means I'll either have to scrap the solution or symlink readmes into every subfolder which is undesirable. I thank you nonetheless for your time.

Comment: I've tried matching too with things like `(\S+)` but it refuses to work... I can confirm however that it _does_ work if I manually specify a subfolder name so it's a problem with the engines ability to capture input...

Comment: Regarding your first comment: In your question, you wrote: *I know for step three I can use an if statement inside the location block to check if the file actually exists instead of blindly trying to use it* That's exactly what you need to do; you won't get away without it, unless you are prepared for some more regex wizardry. It is **intended** that it matches any subfolder when you put it before the general case. Then you check if the subfolder contains readme.php; if not, use `/archive/readme.php`.

Comment: And changing `[^/]` to `[^/]*` definitely changes a lot, because the first one definitely matches exactly one character, while the second one matches all characters until (and excluding) the next `/`. Are you absolutely sure your test methods are correct?

Comment: Alright so lets assume that I've written the inner if statement for simplicity sake. The problem. My test methods consists of directly altering the code I have written in the question to what you have given, (as an example, your `[^/]*`), restarting nginx and checking what it does. I either get 404 errors indicating that the file wasn't actually found, or it doesn't change the behaviour, that is, loading the root readme.php even in subdirectories. As to _why_ it's not found? My educated guess is that `$1` is matching the empty string, and then it literally looks for `/archive//readme.php`...

Comment: Well, as I wrote, I am not sure if nginx's engine follows the first-match logic. IMHO, your third approach (`/archive/(.*)/`) is the easiest one, and should work provided (1) nginx implements a first-match logic and (2) you put it above the general case and (3) you implement the `if`-statement. If that doesn't work either, I am afraid that I can't help any more, due to my lacking knowledge about nginx. The only advice I can give then is to turn on logging as much as possible and to try to learn from the logs where the problem is. Perhaps you can output `$1` somehow for debugging?